# como colocar máscara monetária para EditText em um aplicativo Android?

Tags: java, android, edittext

como colocar máscara monetária para EditText em um aplicativo Android somente com valores numéricos sem o R$, ou seja, imprimir no EditText 2,99? Se tiverem um exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Modifique o onChanged do TextEdit via código que da certo. E vc nem precisa de uma mascara para isso. Segue um exemplo:

```
        seu_text_edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            private String current = "";
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(!s.toString().equals(current)) {
                    Locale myLocale = new Locale("pt", "BR");
                    //Nesse bloco ele monta a maskara para money
                    txtUnitario.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[R$,.]", "");
                    Decimal parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                    String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(myLocale).format((parsed / 100));
                    current = formatted;
                    txtUnitario.setText(formatted);
                    txtUnitario.setSelection(formatted.length());

                    //Nesse bloco ele faz a conta do total (Caso a qtde esteja preenchida)
                    String qtde = txtQtdeLitros.getText().toString();

                    txtUnitario.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Essa é apenas uma maneira básica de fazer um campo monetario, existem muitas outras maneiras de fazer e na minha opinião, esse tipo de campo não precisa de máscara pois é só vc falar que ele é tipo currency e tratar os dados usando Decimal ( Sempre evite trabalhar com valores Double ou Float quando for monetario ).
Detalhe, Usando essa lógica ao invés de uma máscara vc também vai dar um efeito super legal para o EditText, pois ele vai preencher a partir dos centavos.

Comment: É que eu preciso realizar cálculos, posso usar mesmo assim seu código?

Comment: Pode, sem problemas. No meu sistema eu faço um calculo de litros x valor, eu uso esse mesmo código para o valor unitario, litros e total e funciona 100%

Comment: Olá, tive um problema como posso salvar no banco MYSQL o valor gerado? irei salvar como String ele salva nesse formato R$ 2,99 ou posso salvar como Decimal? mas mostra o seguinte erro após salvar em String. Vou postar na edição.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar esta lib:
https://github.com/santalu/mask-edittext

Depois só adicionar o edittext já com mascara no xml:

```
 <com.santalu.maskedittext.MaskEditText
android:id="@+id/et_phone_number"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/hint_phone_number"
android:inputType="number"
app:mask="#,##"/>
```

Comment: Fiz o teste deu certo mas ele só trata valores no formato 1,20 e se caso precisa-se de valor 12,40 ou 1200,00?

Comment: é só mudar a mascara do jeito que você quer por exemplo: Para 12,40 é app:mask="##,##"

Comment: Eu preciso de uma mask que permita apenas letras maiúsculas e números, sem ponto, espaço ou outro caracter, Sabe se atende? Valeu